# Existence of a set with property that all subsets are members

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Within Zermelo Fraenkel Set theory (Edit: Without the axiom of regularity ), Does there exist a nonempty set $X$ with the property that if $Y \subseteq X$, then $Y \in X$?

My guess is no, but currently unable to prove it. Would the set $S = \{ x \in X : x \not\subseteq X \}$ derive a contradiction ? Or is this provable without the axiom of regularity?

Comment: That would imply $X\in X$..

Comment: Without the axiom of regularity, is there any other within ZF to show $X$ cannot be a member of itself? @Berci

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If every subset of $X$ is an element of $X$, then $\mathcal P(X)\subset X$, which contradicts Cantor's theorem that $|X|<|\mathcal P(X)|$ (i.e., that there exists no injection from $\mathcal P(X)$ to $X$).

Cantor's theorem does not need regularity to be proven.

---

Some other objection, is that $X$ contains all ordinals: if $\alpha$ is an ordinal, and for each $\beta<\alpha$ we have $\beta\in X$, then $\alpha\subset X$, thus $\alpha\in X$. This shows that $0\in X$, that $\alpha\in X$ implies $\alpha+1\in X$, and that all limit ordinals are in $X$.